# unable to find route when specifying routes in separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

when I type URL localhost:8000 it displays a message in browser "hello world".
but when I try localhost:8000/product it doesn't find the right path.

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http'); 
const port = 8000;
const app = require('./app');    
http.createServer(function(req,res){
        res.write('Hello World!');
        res.end(); }).listen(port);
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const productRoutes = require('./src/helper/routes/product');

console.log('savan');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


app.use('/product',productRoutes);

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    if(req) {
        console.log('request');
    }
    res.end();
});
```

src/helper/routes/product.js

```
const express = require('express');
const productRoutes = express.Router();

console.log('product');

module.exports = function(productRoutes) {
    productRoutes.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.write('hii');
        res.render('about');
        console.log('get request...');
    });

    productRoutes.post('/',(req, res) => {
        console.log('post request...');
    });

    return productRoutes;
};
```

Comment: Try to change in app.js from ('./src/helper/routes/product') to ('src/helper/routes/product')

Comment: I have tried it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the route file, you need to export the route itself instead of wrapping everything in a function.

```
const express = require('express');
const productRoutes = express.Router();

productRoutes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.write('hii');
    res.render('about');
    console.log('get request...');
});

productRoutes.post('/',(req, res) => {
    console.log('post request...');
});

module.exports = productRoutes;
```

or you could keep the function in the route file and call the function to pass the returned express router to the express app in app.js instead of passing the function directly to express.

```
app.use('/product', productRoutes());
```

Comment: I have tried both 
using module.exports = productRoutes; 

and using the function in route file But I got the same issue.

is there anything that I am missing here ???

Comment: @SavanGotrakiya you can use either of the approaches, but not both at the same time. If that’s what you did and you still get the error, can you send me the updated code so I can take a look?

Comment: **src/helper/product.js**
`const express = require('express');
const productRoutes = express.Router();
console.log('product');
productRoutes.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.write('hii');
        res.render('about');
        console.log('get request...');
});
productRoutes.post('/',(req, res) => {
        console.log('post request...');
});
module.exports = productRoutes;
`

Comment: This above code is my updated code I have tried both approaches separately but still, I got an error.